# Make insert in view work with EF6 and SQLite

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I created a entity based on a sqlite view, and I want to insert data in it using EF6. I altered the .edmx file to make EF see the view as a table and define a primary key on the view.
The problem is that when my program tries to insert data into the view, (which of course has a INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger that insert the data on 2 underlying tables of the view), I get the exception:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
> number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
> entities were loaded. Handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

The underlying query called from EF, is that:

```
Opened connection at 12/07/2019 16:58:18 +02:00
Started transaction at 12/07/2019 16:58:18 +02:00
INSERT INTO [testcasesView]([name], [deviceversion_id], [user_id], [timestamp], [comment], [static_result], [description], [precondition], [action], [expected_result], [reviewed], [automated])
 VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, NULL, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10);
SELECT [id]
FROM [testcasesView]
WHERE last_rows_affected() > 0 AND [id] = last_insert_rowid()
;
-- @p0: 'asd' (Type = String)
-- @p1: '67' (Type = Int64)
-- @p2: '20' (Type = Int64)
-- @p3: '1562943498' (Type = Int64)
-- @p4: 'as' (Type = String)
-- @p5: 'asd' (Type = String)
-- @p6: 'asd' (Type = String)
-- @p7: 'asd' (Type = String)
-- @p8: 'asd' (Type = String)
-- @p9: '0' (Type = Int64)
-- @p10: '0' (Type = Int64)
-- Executing at 12/07/2019 16:58:18 +02:00
-- Completed in 1 ms with result: SQLiteDataReader

Closed connection at 12/07/2019 16:58:18 +02:00
Disposed transaction at 12/07/2019 16:58:18 +02:00
```

I understood why but I don't know if I can solve this. The problem is that since the real insert happens inside the trigger (I don't post the code because it's two simple insert), the query

```
SELECT [id]
FROM [testcasesView]
WHERE last_rows_affected() > 0 AND [id] = last_insert_rowid()
```

Returns no contents, then EF thinks that no rows was affected.

**Is there a statement or code that I can add to my trigger that makes EF see that the insert happened?**